# BASH script to find files that match by content

Tags: bash

I have several thousand .wav files, spanning several levels of subfolders.

A few months back I selected 12 of these and copied them in another folder.

In this new folder, I renamed them 01.wav to 12.wav.

Now I need to figure out what the original files were.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283021/identify-duplicates-and-delete (but sorting them by file size and finding them manually will probably be even easier)

Comment: Unfortunately they're all the same size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the directory where the 12 `wav` files are and execute:

```
cksum {01..12}.wav > cksum.txt
```

Then move `cksum.txt` to the top directory of your `wav` files and `cd` to that directory. Then execute this pipeline:

```
find . -name '*.wav' -exec cksum '{}' + |
awk 'NR == FNR {ck[$1] = $3; next} {if ($1 in ck) print ck[$1], $3}' cksum.txt -
```

This also prints the 12 `wav` files as duplicates of themselves but I left that in for simplicity (although it would be easy to remove them).